# Unable to Detect and handle Slow network connection.(WebServices)

Tags: android, sdk, http-post

I am calling  web service in my activity. If I am connected to Internet it calls Web service otherwise loads data from local SqLite. **If I am connected to hi-speed data connection**, it works correct but, if I am connected through a **slow connection** it shows waiting dialog box and moving continuously, finally my app crashes and stops working. I want to display a proper message if App is connected to a slow connection.

Snips of my code.

```
    conn=new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    isInternetPresent=conn.isConnectedToInternet();
    if(isInternetPresent) {
        startWebServices();
    }else {
        //load data in list view from SQLite
    }
```

//----Calling startWebServices()

```
    public void startWebServices(){
        JSONReadText task=new JSONReadText();
        task.execute(new String[]{url});
    }
```

//----Start JSON READ DATA

```
public class JSONReadText extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    public JSONReadText() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyRegionActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", uid));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            JSONResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            MyRegionActivity.this.finish();

        }
        return null;
    }

    private StringBuffer inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuffer answer = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            MyRegionActivity.this.finish();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        ListDrawer();
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

//----Filling Data to ListView

```
private void ListDrawer() {
        regionList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONArray jsonMain= new JSONArray(JSONResult);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMain.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChild = jsonMain.getJSONObject(i);
                String id=jsonChild.optString("id");
                String name=jsonChild.optString("name");
                String description=jsonChild.optString("description");
                String base_office=jsonChild.optString("base_office");
                regionList.add(new RegionList(id, name, description,base_office));
            }
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            MyRegionActivity.this.finish();
        }
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new RegionListAdapter(MyRegionActivity.this, R.layout.activity_my_region, regionList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: post logcat trash here. and show full code.

Comment: LoginDataBaseAdapter  class is missing? Have you made that adapter class?

Answer (score 1):

Does your project have this class "LoginDataBaseAdapter". Because its in red color which states that its compilation error.